# Why did I get an exception "Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'long?'" when using the LINQ Sum method and how to fix it?

Tags: c#, linq, sum, numbers, decimal

I have the following code which is working:

```
IEnumerable<Decimal?> values = getValues();

var sum = values.Where(x => x > 0).Sum();
```

But if I try:

```
var sum = values.Sum(x => x > 0);
```

I get the error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'long?'
```

Shouldn't this work either applying the filter in Sum or Where?

Comment: Sum expects predicate with return value number, x > 0 is Boolean

Comment: That `Func<>` parameter you're passing to `Sum()` is a selector, not a filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, Sum requires numbers values and not boolean evaluation results.

You need first to filter using [Where](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where) or [Select](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select) (not relevant here) then [Sum](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sum):

```
var sum = values.Where(x => x != null && x > 0).Sum();
```

I added the null check because the collection is type of `decimal?`.

Else you need to write that but this is less speed optimized:

```
var sum = values.Sum(x => x != null && x > 0 ? x : 0);
```

Using a [selector](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sum?view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_Sum__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Decimal__) for Sum is for example usefull when having classes, structs or tuples:

```
var sum = controls.Sum(control => control.Width);
```

Comment: What about simply `var sum = controls.Sum(x => x * 2);` as a use case? Did you run a speed comparison to back that claim?

Comment: @Filburt If you do a sum on 10 items, 5 positives, and 5 negatives that you turn into 0 using a condition on 10, it is slower than add only 5 items selected from that condition.

Comment: The `x * 2` example was hinted at the claim it would only be useful for classes, structs or tuples.

Comment: @Filburt Indeed, that's true.

Answer (score 3):

This code:

```
var sum = values.Sum(x => x > 0);
```

Includes a *lambda expression (anonymous function)* that returns a `bool` (true or false). It's the same as:

```
var sum = values.Sum(x => Check(x));

private bool Check(long x)
{
    return x > 0;
}
```

As you cannot sum a `bool` the code does not work. `Sum()` if passed a parameter expects that parameter to be an enumeration of numbers (`int` or `long` for example, though it has MANY overloads).

Answer (score 1):

As you can see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sum?view=net-5.0) `Enumerable.Sum` does not have an overload which accepts a boolean returning `Func` as an argument. It only has overloads accepting number returning delegates.

How's that useful?

Let's say you have a list of items in the cart and you want to count the total price, you would do it like this:

```
var totalPrice = cartItems.Sum(ci => ci.Price);
```

If you want to filter it first, you have to use `Where`.

Comment: I miss interpret the lambda expression in SUM. Now I got it ... Sum func is just like a Select